# I want to write a generic function to pair two database fields

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming

Let's say that I have two teams, `"red"` and `"black"`. And let's say that I have a `Story` class, which presents similar information in two very different ways, depending on your team:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    red_title = models.CharField()
    black_title = models.CharField()

    red_prologue = models.TextField()
    black_prologue = models.TextField()

    # ... and so on ...

    def get_field(self, genericName, team):
        """Return the field with suffix genericName belonging to the given team.

        >>>self.get_field("prologue", "red") is self.red_prologue
        True
        >>>self.get_field("title", "black") is self.black_title
        True

        """
        assert(team in ["red", "black"])
        specificName = "{}_{}".format(team, genericName)
        return self.__dict__[specificName]
```

I'm happy with the getter function, but I feel like I should be able to refactor the code which created the fields in the first place. I'd like a function that looks something like this:

```
def make_fields(self, genericName, fieldType, **kwargs):
    """Create two fields with suffix genericName.

    One will be 'red_{genericName}' and one will be 'black_{genericName}'.

    """
    for team in ["red", "black"]:
        specificName = "{}_{}".format(team, genericName)
        self.__dict__[specificName] = fieldType(**kwargs)
```

But `self` and `__dict__` are meaningless while the class is first defined, and I think Django requires that database fields be class variables rather than instance variables.

So... is there some way to create this `make_fields` function within Django, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I don't know offhand how to do this (the `Model` metaclass is getting in your way), but have you thought about refactoring by creating a `TeamStory` object, which would have just `title`, `prologue`, etc, and then link `TeamStory`s to a `Story`? This would change the Django admin but everything else should work fairly straightforwardly, and you could easily change your getter to support that.

Comment: Remember that a django model class is a representation of a database table, so if you wouldn't do it to a table in a database, don't do it in the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're even doing this.  A much more sane model would be:

```
TEAMS = (
    ("r","red"),
    ("b","black"),
)

class Story(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TEAMS)
    title = models.CharField()
    prologue = models.TextField()
```

Your current model is creating lots of duplicate columns (for red and black) that should just be defined by a column itself.  Using the model above, you queries would be like `Story.objects.filter(team="r")`.

You then wouldn't need your `get_field` function at all.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that any solutions which create new models and use `filter` to find related items will force us to up the db query count in our views later on.

That said, I think I'll do something like your solution. I'll have a `Story` class which holds a `red_version` and a `black_version`, and I think `select_related` will work well with that. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffHemphill fair enough. A little more info on what you're trying to achieve might help me provide a better solution.  Remember you can select multiple rows with a single query so my solution shouldn't cause an increase in queries if everything else is implemented optimally.

Answer (score 1):

No. A Django model shouldn't be treated as something that can be dyamically constructed; it's a Python representation of a database table. For instance, what would be the semantics of changing the format of `specificName` after you had already run `syncdb`? There's no definitive, obvious answer - so Django doesn't try to answer it. You columns are defined at the class level, and that's that.

(At some level, you can always drill into the internal ORM data structures and set up these fields - but all you're doing is opening yourself up to a world of ambiguity and not-well-defined problems. Don't do it.)